# How to detect text fragments `#:~:text=` with JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

when a user clicks on a featured snippet in Google search results, the text element is highlighted by a text fragment. The browser address looks like `example.com/landing-page#:~:text=Start%20of%20fragment%20an,End%20of%20fragement.`

I now want to detect with JavaScript if a user visits the page with a highlighted text.

I already tried `window.location.hash` and `document.URL` but the value after `#` is not part of the result.

Is that possible with pure JS?

Comment: `window.location.href.includes(":~:text=")` should work for what you want.

Comment: @mamady I get `false` as a response. Also `window.location.href` doesn't show the value after hash.

Comment: @nilobyte Unfortunately it doesn't look like. Seems that Google Chrome remove that part from *any* URL objects, so there is apparently no way to access it.
Unless they provide specific non standard APIs to access to that content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.fragmentDirective` to access what was used for the text fragment.

From MDN: [Programmatic access to text fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments#programmatic_access_to_text_fragments) and [Document: fragmentDirective property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fragmentDirective)

Comment: This does not seem to work. MDN states that the [FragmentDirective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FragmentDirective) is an object exposed for feature detectability, that is, whether or not a browser supports text fragments.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I know, there is no clean and reliable way to do this**.

But it's simple to **remove this text-fragment hash and highlighting** (in typical cases). All what you need is this:

```
if(/\.google\....?\/$/.test(document.referrer)) {
    location.hash= "top";
    history.pushState({}, "", location.pathname);    
}
```

---

**Detection of text-fragments** is possible in cases, where the target text is "**below the fold**" and therefore the page scrolled down to make it visible. Example code:

```
onload= function() {
    if(scrollY) {
        alert("page has scrolled down likley because of text-fragment link");
        // do what you need here
    }
}
```

---

As an **ugly hack**, you can **force this scrolling** by moving all content below the fold and resetting afterwards. Something like this (code has room for improvement):

```
if(/\.google\....?\/$/.test(document.referrer) {

    // add margin to <body> - move content down to force scrolling
    document.body.style.marginTop= "111vh";

    onload= function() {
        if(scrollY) {
            alert("page has scrolled down likley because of text-fragment link");
            // do what you need here
        }

        // reset margin
        document.body.style.marginTop= "";
    } 
}
```